# Cant bootstrap angular 1.x app with webpack and index.js files

Tags: angularjs, webpack

So, i have a webpack config file which works:

```
var webpack =  require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var ChunkManifestPlugin = require("chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin");
var WebpackChunkHash = require("webpack-chunk-hash");
var OpenBrowserPlugin =  require("open-browser-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports =  {
entry: {
    main: './index.js',
    vendors: './vendors.js'
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body'}),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        names: ['vendor', 'manifest'],
        minChunks: function (module) {
            return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
        }
    }),
    new ChunkManifestPlugin({
        filename: "chunk-manifest.json",
        manifestVariable: "webpackManifest"
    }),
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new WebpackChunkHash(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new OpenBrowserPlugin({ url: 'http://localhost:3000' }),
],
devtool: "inline-source-map",
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "app"),
    watchContentBase: true,
    watchOptions: {
        poll: true
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    clientLogLevel: 'error'
 }
};
```

now, this is my folder structure:

```
|-- root
|-- index.html
|-- index.js
|-- package.json
|-- vendors.js
|-- webpack.config.js
|-- app
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- shared
|       |-- index.js
|       |-- navbar
|           |-- index.js
```

vendors.js:

```
require('angular');
require('moment');
```

index.js:

```
module.exports = function () {
 require('./app')();
};
```

app/index.js:

```
var angular = require('angular');
module.exports = function () {
    angular.module('app', []);
};
```

my index.html has a `<html ng-app="app">` binding

but when i run my webpack no such module can be found
im not sure what im missing since i see in the index.html all the bundles.

im getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Try this. `var app = angular.module ('app', []); module.exports = () => angular.bootstrap(document.body, app.name);` and then remove the ng-app

Comment: didn't work, switched it to es5 and nothing

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by switched it to es5

Comment: Wait a second, I think I see the problem here, **index.js** should be `var appFactory = require('./app'); var app = appFactory(); module.exports = app;` I totally missed that the angular module 'app' is never created

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your *top level* index.js file does not create your `angular.module` it exports a function which creates it. Since this function is never called, the module is never registered with AngularJS which results in the indicated error.

Your current top level index.js file looks like

```
module.exports = function () {
  require('./app')();
};
```

This defines a CommonJS module whose value is a function that dynamically imports and registers the angular application. 
Since we want to bootstrap the application, the easiest way would be to change the top level index.js file to

```
require('./app')();
```

Note there is no wrapper and no export.

If we want to expose the app for import by another module, while still bootstrapping it, we can instead write

```
module.exports = require('./app')();
```

Comment: Would you care to accept this answer if it worked for you? :)